# How do I update my HTML Selects with ajax based on other Selects?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, html-select

I've got this search page with 7 different Selects and 2 textfields.
The data wich is stored in the selects is fetched from a MYSQL database.

Now when I make a choice, I want the other selects to update based on the choise I made.
This needs to be accomplished with Ajax. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. There are many AJAX tutorials, you can also look at some of the questions in the Related sidebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF your're using jquery there is an discussion: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-reload-a-select-in-a-form-using-ajax-via-jquery

Answer (score 1):

collect the values of already filled selects, and send them to the server to obtain the filtered values list.

let's say you have an car manufacturer / model selector.

```
<select name="manufacturer">
 <option value="1">Acura</option>
 <option value="2">Audi</option>
 ...
</select>

<select name="model"></select>
```

the function to fill "model" select with values should look like this:

```
$.get('/get_models_by_manufacturer', {manuf: $('select[name=manufacturer']).val()}, function(data){ 
  // data returned by the server is expected to be html code of options NOT surrounded with <select>
  $('select[name=model]').html(data);
});
```